# GTK and python. How convert RGBA to HEX?

Tags: python, gtk

```
        # a colorbutton (which opens a dialogue window in
        # which we choose a color)
        self.button_err_bg = Gtk.ColorButton()
        # with a default color (blue, in this instance)
        color_bg = Gdk.RGBA()
        color_bg.red = 0.5
        color_bg.green = 0.4
        color_bg.blue = 0.3
        color_bg.alpha = 1.0
        color_error_background = self.button_err_bg.set_rgba(color_bg)

        # choosing a color in the dialogue window emits a signal
        self.button_err_bg.connect("color-set", self.on_color_fg_error_chosen)
```

and method

```
    def on_color_fg_error_chosen(self, user_data):
        print("You chose the color: " + self.button_err_bg.get_rgba().to_string())
        color_rgba = self.button.get_rgba().to_string()
        color_rgba_bracket = color_rgba[color_rgba.find("(")+1:color_rgba.find(")")]
        color_hex = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(color_rgba_bracket)
        print(color_hex)
```

color_hex :color_hex = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(color_rgba_bracket)
ValueError: Unknown format code 'x' for object of type 'str'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code, I'm going to assume that `self.button.get_rgba()` returns a tuple.

Since you convert the assumed tuple to a string (for some reason), the format fails because, as your error shows, it doesn't know how to convert a string to hex. Additionally, even if it *did* have an `x` format for a string, it would fail with `IndexError: tuple index out of range` because it's expecting 3 items and you're only passing 1.

If you skip the string conversion altogether, and unpack the tuple, you should get a proper format:

```
def on_color_fg_error_chosen(self, user_data):
    print("You chose the color: " + self.button_err_bg.get_rgba().to_string())
    color_rgba = self.button.get_rgba()
    color_hex = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(*color_rgba)
    print(color_hex)
```

Using a basic example:

```
>>> color_rgba = (12, 28, 200, 28) # R, G, B, Alpha
>>> '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(*color_rgba) # 4th item is ignored because only looking for 3 items
'#0c1cc8'
```